# Trying to get the intuition behind ^.{5}[^e]?$ for Order in regex golf

Tags: regex

I'm trying to get a better understanding of how the question mark works in the regular expression

```
^.{5}[^e]?$
```

for regex golf (https://regex.alf.nu/8).

Right now I read it as 'given the start of the string, take any 5 characters that are not followed by an e, end string. The question mark reads as if the 5 characters are not followed by an e or any character, then that's the end of the string.

I used regexper.com (http://www.regexper.com/#^.{5}[^e]%3F%24) to help me understand but I don't think that I'm understanding the ? correctly.

How does the ? work in comparison to negative lookaheads, etc.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: The question mark is an optional quantifier meaning "zero or one" times of any character except: `e`. So your regex says match, `the beginning of the string, any character except \n (5 times) followed by any character except: 'e' (optional) and the end of the string`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> that are not followed by an e

Not exactly. The correct description would be "*that are followed by an not-e*" - that's what a [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) does. And for such a not-e it does make sense to be optional.

What really would read "*not followed by*" is a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), and indeed if those are optional then they don't make sense (as in: they can be omitted).

Answer (score 0):

"?" is the "optional" quantifier - ie *zero or one* of the preceding term.

The whole regex means *any 5 characters with an optional 6th character that is not an "e"*, eg "eeeee" and "eeeeex" would both match.